# How can I extend layout.html

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm using sphinx 1.2.2 and [readthedocs.ru](http://readthedocs.org) with default theme(sphinx_rtd_theme).

How I can extend `layout.html`? The following code does not work:

```
#_templates/layout.html
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
  {{ super() }}
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Mono&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: When you say that your code "does not work", what do you mean exactly?  Are you seeing an error message from Sphinx?  Or does it just have no effect?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @SamWhited No, I didn't.

Comment: Ah, poor; I ended up working around the issue (by extending page.html instead of layout.html), but I'd much rather be extending layout. I know there was work towards fixing this on RTD, but the pull request appears to be abandoned. I'll ping them on IRC later and find out.

Comment: @SamWhited Please post a link to PR here.

Comment: Sorry, should have said "issue", not "pull request": https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/152 I asked on IRC but never got a response. Will post an answer if I ever do.